# Awk - output the second line of a number of .dat files to one file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, text-processing, awk, io-redirection

I have multiple files something like: (in reality i have 80)

file1.dat

```
2 5

6 9

7 1
```

file2.dat

```
3 7

8 4

1 3
```

I want to end up with a file containing all of the second lines. i.e.

output.dat

```
6 9

8 4
```

What i have so far loops though the file names but then over-writes the file before it. e.g. the output of the above files would just be

```
8 4
```

my shell script looks like this:

post.sh

```
TEND = 80

TINDX = 0

while [ $TINDX - lt $TEND]; do

awk '{ print NR==2 "input-$TINDX.dat > output.dat

TINDX = $((TINDX+1))

done
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove `while` loop and make use of shell brace expansion and also `FNR`, a built-in `awk` variable:

```
awk 'FNR==2{print $0 > "output.dat"}' file{1..80}.dat
```

Comment: even shorter `awk 'FNR==2' file{1..80}.dat > output.dat`

Answer (score 9):

`sed` would be enough:

```
sed -sn 2p file{1..80}.dat > output.dat
```

`-s` option is needed to print 2nd line from each file, otherwise only 2nd line of first file will be printed.

Answer (score 8):

What about ...
`head -n 2 input.dat | tail -n 1 | awk` ...

Comment: Yes, `head`/`tail` is definitely an option, you don't need `awk` then.

Answer (score 2):

aragaer’s `sed` solution is nicest, yes. But I since I do enjoy a bit of `head|tail` cutting, have a `head|tail` solution that supports multiple files, not just a single `input.dat`. Using a for-loop, instead of passing a list of files to sed, also makes it easier to do other thing with the file before/after extracting the second line with sed.

```
# empty output.dat first
rm output.dat

# have a one-liner
for file in *.dat; do head -2 $file | tail -1 >> output.dat; done
```

Copiously-commented multi-line version:

NB: the code below will run. We are free to put a linebreak after a `|`, `&&`, or `||`, and continue our command on the next line; we can even put comments in between. I spent *years* not knowing this (and not really seeing it anywhere). This style is less useful at the interactive prompt, but cleans up script files no end.

```
# empty output.dat first
rm output.dat

for file in *.dat; do
    # file -> lines 1 and 2 of file
    head -2 $file |
    # lines 1 and 2 of file -> line 2 of file >> appended to output.dat
    tail -1 >> output.dat
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously lots of ways to do this - I think I like [@aragaer's sed answer best](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178889/34061).

Here's one that uses purely bash builtins and doesn't need to fork any external utilities:

```
for f in file{1..80}.dat; do
    { read && read && printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; } < "$f"
done > output.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency use of `awk` and `sed` in answers here on multiple files, better to use `nextfile` statement to skip processing unwanted lines in `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==2{ print >"output.dat"; nextfile}' infile{1..80}.dat
```

and with `sed`, we can exit when processing on 3<sup>rd</sup> line and `sed` will process the next file.

```
sed -sn '2p;3q' infile{1..80}.dat > output.dat
```